# Pressing enter when editing cell, moving to next cell to edit

Tags: tabulator

Using Tabulator, how do I set it up so that when the user pressed Enter after editing a cell's value, it moves to the next cell (like Tab).  I have a table where only the first column is set to be editable.  I've enabled keybindings so I can use the arrow key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use a custom editor and bind an event listener to the input so that when user presses the enter key, the focus moves onto the next editable cell by calling `table.navigateNext()`.  Here is an example where only first column is editable:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '', cheese: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982', cheese: true },
  { id: 10, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '16', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1999' }
]

function customEditor(cell, onRendered, success, cancel) {
  const input = document.createElement('input')
  input.value = cell.getValue()

  onRendered(() => {
    input.focus()
  })

  function onChange() {
    if (input.value != cell.getValue()) {
      success(input.value)
    } else {
      cancel()
    }
  }

  input.addEventListener('blur', onChange)

  input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      table.navigateNext()

      onChange()
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
      cancel()
    }
  })

  return input
}

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: data,
  columns: [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', editor: customEditor },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age' },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender' },
    { title: 'Height', field: 'height' },
    { title: 'Color', field: 'col' }
  ]
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!  One question, how can I achieve the equivalent of `selectContents: true` in a custom editor?

Comment: Just replace `input.focus()` with `input.select()` inside the `onRendered` callback.

Comment: Works, thanks again!